# Type of redirect: 301 Moved Permanently in IIS

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config, http-status-code-301

I have domain test.abc.com which is redirect to www.test.abc.com in IIS hosted server.

My question is -> How can I remove this redirection-301 Moved Permanently in IIS hosted server web site?

I have checked web.config file and IIS Server for redirect rule and I found that there is no any issue or code for redirect rule in web.config file as well as in IIS server.
Is there anything else I have to check then please suggest.

Comment: Capture packets from both clients and server. That at least gives you some hints on what to check next.

Comment: @LexLi I didnt get you please explain me how I will capture client and server request without installing third party software.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/yongrhee/archive/2012/12/01/network-tracing-packet-sniffing-built-in-to-windows-server-2008-r2-and-windows-server-2012.aspx